# What is the simplest method to write a file with Chrome file interface?

Tags: javascript

Chrome implements the file interface as described here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/, just adding the `webkit` prefix. The documentation covers several aspects of the interface, but what are the simplest steps, for example, to prompt the user with a file saving dialog, or to tell him that the file has been saved somewhere? For example, let's say we want to save some text data for the user.

I'm mainly referring to lines of code as a metric of simplicity, but within the 80 characters per line (and common sense). I'm also referring to Chrome 26.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found. Naturally, it's use is quite limited, and it is better to refer to the main article linked above

```
function error(e) { console.log(e); };
webkitRequestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, Math.pow(2, 10), function(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile( 'exported.txt', {create:true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
                alert('content saved to '+fileEntry.fullPath);
            };
            var blob = new Blob(['Lorem Ipsum'], {type: 'text/plain'});
            fileWriter.write(blob);
        });
    }, error);
}, error);
```